# Controllers, views and accepts_nested_attributes_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a view 'business', that contains 3 partials (about, hours, and vacations) that each have an edit mode. 'business' accepts_nested_attributes_for each of these. Should these 3 forms all call the business controllers 'update' method and just save the nested attributes (meaning the same code could handle all 3 forms), and update the appropriate partial depending on which form was submitted? Or should they call their own controllers, i.e. hours form calls hours controller, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Both approaches could be plausible depending on how you handle the submitted data for each of them. If you will be submitting only one of those sub-resources, it is logical to use their own controllers. If it makes sense to change and submit them all together at once, then go for  the main resource's controller.